# Youtube Embed Video Through a VPN in PHP

Tags: php, vpn

I have a website www.saazawaz.com which uses embed videos from Youtube. Youtube is forbidden in our country and we have use Hotspot Shield for Youtube. I want that when a visitor come from our country to www.saazawaz.com, my website automatically bypass the youtube embed link to the user and the user dont need to install hotspot shield. Is there a script to use the embed youtube video.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what country would that be?

Comment: pakistan here the local broadband connection not allows youtube.